# Using awk to retrieve a specific set of strings from a file

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, awk

textFileA consists of:

```
mango:oval:yellow:18pcs
apple:irregular:red:12pcs
orange:round:orange:4pcs
```

I wanted to do something like allowing user input for example user search "mango"
I want the system to print out

Please enter the fruit name : **mango** >> this is user input

**Desire Output**

```
Fruit Shape : Oval
Fruit Color : Yellow
Fruit Quantity : 18pcs
```

So far this is what i done and it could only print out the entire line of strings, did i do something wrong here?

```
echo -n "Please enter the fruit name :"
read fruitName
awk '/'$fruitName'/ {print}'  textFileA
```

**Current Output**

```
mango:oval:yellow:18pcs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```sh
read -p "Please enter the fruit name: " fruitName
awk -F: -v fruitName="$fruitName" '
$1 == fruitName {
   print "Fruit Shape :", $2
   print "Fruit Color :", $3
   print "Fruit Quantity :", $4
}' file
```

**Output:**

```sh
Please enter the fruit name: mango
Fruit Shape : oval
Fruit Color : yellow
Fruit Quantity : 18pcs
```

Comment: but may i know what is the purpose of -F and -v ?

Comment: `-F` is for setting field separator as `:` and `-v` is for passing a command line argument to `awk` (in this case `$fruitName`)

Comment: i was tryiing to but for some reason it requires me to wait for few minutes

Comment: Hi @anubhava, may i know how is it possible to assign the string value to a variable that i have retrieve using the awk? if it can can can you show me a sample?

Comment: I want to assign the specific string, for example "oval" to a variable, because i wanted to use this string later, isit possible sir? I know the string column is located at $2 but i just dont know how to assign@anubhava

Comment: Use: `var=$(awk -F: -v fruitName="$fruitName" '$1 == fruitName {print $2}' file`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to format string by inserting certain values inside it you might find useful [`printf` Statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html), consider following example, let `file.txt` content be

```
mango:oval:yellow:18pcs
apple:irregular:red:12pcs
orange:round:orange:4pcs
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}/mango/{printf "Shape %s\nColor %s\nQuantity %s\n",$2,$3,$4}' file.txt
```

output

```
Shape oval
Color yellow
Quantity 18pcs
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator is `:` (read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/) if you want to know more) then for line containg `mango` I `printf` string, `%s` are replace with values of columns: 2nd (`$2`) 3rd (`$3`) 4th (`$4`), `\n` denotes newline, so this printf does output multiline string. Note trailing newline, as by default `printf` does not include it at end.

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F: 'BEGIN {printf "Please enter fruit name: "; getline fruit < "-"} $1==fruit {print "Fruit Shape: " $2 "\nFruit Color: " $3 "\nFruit Quantity: " $4}' input_file
Please enter fruit name: mango
Fruit Shape: oval
Fruit Color: yellow
Fruit Quantity: 18pcs
```

```
$ cat file.awk
BEGIN {
    printf "Please enter fruit name: "; getline fruit < "-"
} $1==fruit {
    print "Fruit Shape: " $2 "\nFruit Color: " $3 "\nFruit Quantity: " $4
}
```

```
$ awk -F: -f file.awk input_file
Please enter fruit name: mango
Fruit Shape: oval
Fruit Color: yellow
Fruit Quantity: 18pcs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure Bash way:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the fruit name: " tgt 

keys=("Fruit Shape" "Fruit Color" "Fruit Quantity") 

while IFS= read -r line; do
    arr=(${line//:/ })
    if [[ "${arr[0]}" = "$tgt" ]]; then
        for (( i=0; i<"${#keys[@]}"; i++ )); do 
            echo "${keys[$i]}: ${arr[( $i+1 )]}"
        done
        break 
    fi  
done <file
```